# Which directory does Mac OS X 10.10.x keep iPhone back up file？

Tags: macos, iphone, itunes, backup, back-to-my-mac

I backed up my old iPhone 5S with iTunes on Mac OS X 10.10，But It seems that it's not easy to find the folder. (In Windows，It's `C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Roaming\Apple Computer\MobileSync\backup`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is what you are looking for.

```
    ~/Library/Application Support/MobileSync/Backup/
```